# How git decides what commit modifies a given path? Inconsistent results obtained

Tags: git, merge

When I use `git rev-list` (or `git log`) with the `--` option to restrict commits to those that modify a path, I am getting resuls where I fail to see the consistency.  Worse than that, results vary with git version (pre 1.8.4, results were consistent; in 1.8.4 or 2.5.0 they don't seem consistent to me, and they are different than in older versions; I rather like more the pre 1.8.4 behaviour).

Inconsistencies (inside same git version) or differences (across versions) affects only to merge commits that affect (depending on definition) to a file.  I am not sure if "modifies a given path" means here "file is different in parent commits of a merge", or "file was changed by a commit"

```
git rev-list A..B -- foo
```

Here is an example where I find the results that confuse me:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

git init
git commit --allow-empty -m initial

# Create four branches, one enclosing the previous one
echo v1 > version
git add version
git commit -m v1
git branch b1

echo v2 > version
git add version
git commit -m v2
git branch b2

echo v3 > version
git add version
git commit -m v3
git branch b3

echo v4 > version
git add version
git commit -m v4
git branch b4

git tag checkpoint
# We create a couple of merges
git checkout -b b2_3 b2
git merge --no-ff b3

git checkout -b b1_4 b1
git merge --no-ff b4

# This prints nothing on git < 1.8.4; prints a commit that corresponds with
# "Merge branch 'b3' into b2_3" in git >= 1.8.4 (tested with 1.8.4 and 2.5.0)
echo COMMITS checkpoint..b2_3: $(git rev-list checkpoint..b2_3 -- version)
# This prints nothing on any git version I tested.
echo COMMITS checkpoint..b1_4: $(git rev-list checkpoint..b1_4 -- version)
```

Quoting `man git-rev-list`:

```
Commits are included if they are not TREESAME to any parent
```

(commits that do not modify the file are TREESAME; that section of man page is identical in old and new git versions).  According to this, only git < 1.8.4 is behaving correctly if I am understanding the doc correctly.

Comment: Interesting, `git rev-list b3..b2_3` gives obviously the same result as `git rev-list checkpoint..b2_3`, yet `git rev-list b3..b2_3 -- version` comes up empty.